# Aborted (core dumped) during recursive merge sort

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, mergesort, coredump

Having problems implementing recursive merge sort while passing by reference. basic_merge_sort is the entry point from main.cpp where I pass by value because Im using the same array for a bunch of sorts. The error Im getting is `malloc(): invalid size (unsorted) Aborted (core dumped)`, using gcc and a Makefile. Using a static member from the Counter class to keep track of comparisons during recursion as well. I also tried not to work with pointers but with a static class member vector, but no luck. Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
#include "merge.hpp"
#include "selection.hpp"

using namespace std;

int Counter::count{0}; //lets start count from 0

int basic_merge_sort(vector<double> holder_array) //entry point
{
    int end = holder_array.size() - 1;
    mpartition(&holder_array, 0, end);
    return Counter::count;
}

void merge_sort(vector<double> *holder_array, int start, int end, int middle)
{
    int i = start, j = middle + 1, k = 0;
    vector<double> temp(end - start + 1, 0.0); 

    while (i <= middle && j <= end)
    {
        if (holder_array->at(i) < holder_array->at(j))
        {
            temp[k] = holder_array->at(i); 
            k++;
            i++;
            Counter::count++;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[k] = holder_array->at(j);
            k++;
            j++;
            Counter::count++;
        }
    }

    while (i <= middle)
    {
        temp[k] = holder_array->at(i);
        k++;
        i++;
        Counter::count++;
    }

    while (j <= end)
    {
        temp[k] = holder_array->at(j);
        k++;
        j++;
        Counter::count++;
    }
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        holder_array->at(i) = temp[i - start];
    }
}

void mpartition(vector<double> *holder_array, int start, int end)
{
    int middle;
    if (start < end)
    {
        middle = (start + end) / 2;
        mpartition(holder_array, start, middle);
        mpartition(holder_array, middle + 1, end);
        merge_sort(holder_array, start, end, middle);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's at least one obvious bug in the shown code. Unfortunately, it fails to meet the requirements of a [mre], and as such it is not possible to authoritatively answer that this is the only problem. There could be others, so a [mre] is required to conclusively answer this question. Please [edit] your question so that the shown code complies with all requirements of a [mre]. For more help, see stackoverflow.com's [help], and [ask] questions here.

Comment: `vector<double> temp[end - start + 1]; ` what is this?

Comment: @Quimby that is the temporary storage for the elements being stored, that will go back into the original vector, we need it since we are using recursion afaik.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for the quick reply, can you just mention what the obvious bug is? Also I am missing the points where my question doesnt meet the requirements of a minimal reproducible example, I mentioned that basic_merge_sort gets called from main.cpp, and it gets passed a vector<double> by value. Do I need to include my libraries? My main.cpp? I truly dont understand what is missing here to be reproducible.

Comment: `*temp` aka `temp[0]` is an empty vector. `temp->at(k)` (which is equivalent to `(*temp).at(k)` and `temp[0].at(k)`) would throw `std::out_of_range` exception for any value of `k`

Comment: The bug is `vector<double> temp[end - start + 1]`. This doesn't do what you think it does. Use your debugger to see what `temp` ***really*** is, and the problem should be very obvious.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I also tried to initialize with `vector<double> temp(end - start + 1, 0.0)`, so idk

Comment: Well, nobody could possibly know what you did or did not try. Which is why you must show a [mre].

Comment: So show the code with that line, then.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I modfied it, even though it had a comment right next to the temp initialization, still not working.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you mean Valgrind? I feel lost everytime I try to read its input, can you comment on what you think `vector<double> temp`  _really_ is

Comment: `valgrind` is not a debugger. `gdb` is a debugger. As far as what it really is, it is not even valid C++. Variable length arrays are not standard C++, and are just a gcc extension. Furthermore, it is the same thing that anything else is, that's declared in the same syntax. If it was declared as `int temp[end-start+1];`, what would it be?

Comment: *"invalid size"* -- I'd think the obvious question to ask is what is this size / why is it invalid? (Do some debugging to see which line the crash is on, then look at the values of your variables at that point.)

Comment: The example code will not compile as-is, due to a few syntax issues. After adjusting for those, the program did not crash for me, even after I made sure my source vector was not empty. (If you let me select the input, I'm inclined to pick something that will trivially pass the test.) Thus, a [mre] is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you are not passing the vector by reference: `basic_merge_sort` takes a copy of the vector, hence does not sort the array passed to it but merely a copy.
- `mpartition` takes a pointer to a vector, which is not exactly the same as passing by reference.
- the convention to exclude `end` is confusing and error prone, you should use a more idiomatic convention in C++ and consider the upper bounds to be excluded.

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
#include "merge.hpp"
#include "selection.hpp"

using namespace std;

int Counter::count{0}; //lets start count from 0

int basic_merge_sort(vector<double>& array)
{
    mpartition(array, 0, array.size());
    return Counter::count;
}

void merge_sort(vector<double>& array, size_t start, size_t middle, size_t end)
{
    size_t i = start, j = middle, k = 0;
    vector<double> temp(end - start, 0.0); 

    while (i < middle && j < end) {
        if (array[i] < array[j]) {
            temp[k++] = array[i++]; 
            Counter::count++;
        } else {
            temp[k++] = array[j++];
            Counter::count++;
        }
    }

    while (i < middle) {
        temp[k++] = array[i++];
        Counter::count++;
    }

    while (j < end) {
        temp[k++] = array[j++];
        Counter::count++;
    }
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        array[i] = temp[i - start];
    }
}

void mpartition(vector<double>& array, size_t start, size_t end)
{
    if (end - start >= 2) {
        size_t middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        mpartition(holder_array, start, middle);
        mpartition(holder_array, middle, end);
        merge_sort(holder_array, start, middle, end);
    }
}
```